# C# как скомпилировать проект в один файл?

Tags: c#, компиляция, exe, консоль, .net-6

Вот мой проект, почему блин, exe файл не может работать один? Мне нужно чтобы был всего лишь один exe файл, если я удалю один какой-то файл то он не открывается. Мне такое не надо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема?
P.S( пишу утром, измученный, 6 утра... пора мне спать..).

UPD:
Net 6.0, консольное приложение.

Comment: Ссылка на дубликат вверху, `.pdb` файл не требуется для исполнения, он нужен только для отладки, можете его удалить в собранном приложении.

Comment: Если это у вас cli, то какой смысл беспокоится о кол-ве файлов? Настройте проект как nuget пакет, будет в итоге один файлик `.nupkg`, его уже потом и устанавливайте через [dotnet tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools). Можете даже его опубликовать, на сайте NuGet, будет [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSRcj.png). И вот вам уже один файл для установки, а также сайт, куда можете без труда загрузить если надо. Ну а после регистрации в системе просто вызывайте по имени, например у меня есть CLI `grab`, я пишу это прям в пути директории и моя софтина вызывается.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - вы уверены? Хочу ещё сказать что я сделал CLI под все OS (Linux, MacOS, Windows) не у всех ос есть какой нить дотнет. А мне это важно чтобы был всего лишь один exe файл.

Comment: А разве я должен быть уверенным в вашем проекте, или всеж вы? Не я его разработчик, я не знаю всех тонкостей поставленной задачи. `чтобы был всего лишь один exe` - не все OS используют `.exe` в качестве исполняемого файла, вы не запустите `.exe` файл в MacOS например или Linux без эмуляторов, а вот `dotnet tool` - везде будет работать одинаково, вот к примеру [выдержка из документации](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6FFu.png), как видите, все OS, одинаковой консольной командой.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что именно возмущает... Фрейворк так работает по умолчанию. Если подключить либы еще и они там будут, со всеми ихними зависимостями. Судя по папке это даже не публикация, а простой билд. Если хочется совсем один файл то можно делать так: [Single-file deployment and executable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli).